# Can I earn the bounty I started in this case?

Tags: support, bounty

In the help center, it says

> You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.

Suppose I started a bounty, at mean time, I posted an answer.

If my answer is the highest voted answer, and I did not manually award the bounty. Will I be awarded the bounty by the system?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you still tweaking this question? Nothing wrong with doing that, of course, but you already have your answer: it’s “no”. The best and simplest way to model bounties in your own mind is that *once you post the bounty, it is **gone forever**, no matter what comes or doesn’t come, no matter what you do or don’t do*. Like buying an ad (or a lottery ticket). You pays your money and you takes your chances.

Answer (score 8):

No.  You cannot be awarded a bounty that you started by the system.

Comment: In this case, who will earn the bounty?

Comment: No one.  If no one is eligible, no one will claim it.

Comment: @Sun Or if there is another qualifying answer that isn't yours, that one will get the points.